# How to modify last posts block without losing modification on next WP update

Tags: updates

I need to modify the `wp-includes/blocks/latests-posts.php` but whenever i update wordpress core the modification are lost.
What is the best practice to modify such blocks?

UPDATE:

The only issue I found online similar to my problem, is this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/latest-posts-block/
and here look like people suggest to keep a local copy of the php file and restore every time WP core needs to be updates... !!!

Comment: What specifically are you trying to modify?

Comment: I need to modify the look and to add some extra custom field in the latest posts